# pull userId from DB with email and store user ID in session

Tags: php, mysql

So here is my code for the login page for my site, I want it to pull the user ID from the DB when the user logs in and store it in the session data. WHich I will be using in another page to pull a value from a different table.

```
<?php
session_start();
//Connect to DB
include_once 'db_connect.php';

// escape variables for security
$Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
$Password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['password']);
//password hashing
$Password = hash("sha256", $Password);

$sqli="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email='$Email' and Password='$Password'";
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqli);

//Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);



// If result matched $Email and $Password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

//redirect to file "menu.html"

header("location:menu.html");
}
//If all else fails they shall not pass!
else {
echo "Wrong Email or Password. YOU SHALL NOT PASS!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Code will be improved fro security this is more of a get the functionality working version then polish it up

Comment: I dont see a question??

Comment: Question is how do i get the userID and then store it in the session data?

Comment: if($count==1){

//redirect to file "menu.html"
While(mysql_fetch_array($result)=$row){ $userName = $row['username'] ;$_SESSION['username'] = $userName }
header("location:menu.html");
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ID from the table on your database use **mysqli_fetch_array** or **mysqli_fetch_assoc**

Insert this below your **$result**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): //fetching the row from database

   $id = $row['id']; //the id column in your table
   $_SESSION['id'] = $id; //the id is now saved in your session for future use

endwhile;
```

In another page don't forget to **session_start();** to access $_SESSION['id'] so that you can access different information associated with that id from the table in your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($count == 1) {
    //redirect to file "menu.html" 
    While ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $userName = $row['username']; // Where username is the user ID value in your db
        $_SESSION['username'] = $userName;
        header("location:menu.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so what you need to do is fetch the user id from the database. Presuming the `users` table has a column called `id`:

```
$result=mysqli_query($mysqli, $sqli);

//Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $Email and $Password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['userID']=$row['id'];

    header("location:menu.html");
    die();
}
```

Note that `mysql_fetch_array` is usually called within a while loop, to get multiple rows. However here you only have one row, so that is not needed